# Move UIPopoverController when UIKeyboard appears

Tags: ios, uipopovercontroller, uikeyboard

How do I move the `UIPopoverController` when a keyboard appears? 
Prior to iOS 9/8, when keyboard appears, `UIPopovercontroller` will move accordingly and `UITextField` will not be blocked. 
However since iOS8/9, now it will show the `InputAssistantBar` and it's blocking the `UITextField`, is there any way that `UIPopoverController` will reposition itself?
Thanks!